# Postgresql Jsonb field validation

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using postgresql as a document store for a microservice. The data is denormalized and I only need simple querying, updating, and deletion of documents representing the service's main domain entity. I would like to know if it's possible to do jsonb field validation against another sql table. For example:

Json document:

```
{
  "state": "NY",
  "city": "Brooklyn",
}
```

I would then like to have a sql table full of valid States and Cities in the US, lets call it "GeoLocations", and perform field validation against the json document. The validation logic would be "Before committing this json object confirm that json->>'state' is present in table "GeoLocations". If the state field of the json document does not contain a string that's also within the GeoLocations.State column the constraint should fail and the json document should not be added to the json document table.

Here is how I'm currently creating constraints:

```
-- Create users table
CREATE TABLE users ( u jsonb NOT NULL);

-- Default GIN index over entire document
CREATE INDEX idxginusers ON users USING GIN (u);

-- Force username to be unique
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_username ON users( (u->>'username') );

-- Force username to be non-null
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT username_must_exist CHECK (u ?    'username');

-- Force username not to be empty string
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT username_must_not_be_empty_string CHECK ((u->>'username') != '');

--Force password to be non-null
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT password_must_exist CHECK (u ? 'password');

-- Force password not to be empty string
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT password_must_not_be_empty_string CHECK ((u->>'password') != '');
```

Not relevant to this example - but this is syntax that is working.

I'm leaning toward attempting this with a "CHECK" constraint but not quite sure how to go about that.

Comment: Why don't you simply normalize your data model and use proper foreign keys?

Comment: Coming from MongoDB - Find this simpler when an API is the gateway for ever accessing this entity.